# PreferredStatusBarStyle not called on iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

I have a very interesting situation up in my hands. As you know when you override `preferredStatusBarStyle` of a `UIViewController` and have set the needed flag in `Info.plist` to `true` we should have per view controller status bar style.

It all goes perfect on iOS 16, but for some reason even after calling `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` on iOS 15 it doesn't even enter the overridden property.

It may have something to do with the fact that I am wrapping `UIViewController` inside `SwiftUI` lifecycle.

```swift
@main
struct AppTestingApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Wrapper()
        }
    }
}

struct Wrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        MyViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        .lightContent
    }
}
```